# Method definition with nested parameters?

Tags: python

Why does this method definition use extra parentheses around two of the arguments?

```
def _myFunc(self, (arg_two, arg_three)):
    Queue._put(self, (arg_two, arg_three))
```

What does this mean and in what versions of Python does this work?

Comment: Is this a standalone function? Or is it part of a class definition?

Comment: Also it's generally bad practice to be calling methods that are denoted as private (by the leading underscore) - you shouldn't need to do this.

Comment: you could have just tried to run it ...

Comment: The leading underscore `_` character indicates it's a private function. It's probably a method of some class since its first argument is named `self`. "private" means not a part of the public API of the class and should only be called by other methods of the class (and _possibly_ also any subclasses it might have). This is also applies to functions in a module (which generally don't call their first argument `self`). This is all by convention, so it'll "work" in any version of Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're asking about the method signature.

```
def _myFunc(self, (arg_two, arg_three)):
```

This means it takes two arguments: `self`, and a tuple consists of two elements, `arg_two` and `arg_three`.

```
>>> def f((a, b)):
...   print a, b
...
>>> f((1, 2))
1 2
```

Read more here: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/

Answer (score 3):

Python 2 function definitions let you nest *argument unpacking* arguments; this is syntax similar to assignment unpacking.

E.g. the ability to do this:

```
foo = (2, 3)
a, (b, c) = 1, foo
```

is extended to function signatures. See the [function definition documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions); the `parameter` grammar rule allows for arbitrarily nested sublists:

> ```
> sublist        ::=  parameter ("," parameter)* [","]
> parameter      ::=  identifier | "(" sublist ")"
> ```

Any sublist argument requires *one* outer argument that is a sequence that unpacks to the number of elements in the sublist. Thus:

```
def foo(bar, (baz, spam)):
```

requires two arguments, with the second argument being a sequence of two values. The first argument then is assigned to the `bar` parameter, and the two values in the second argument are assigned to the `baz` and `spam` parameters.

The syntax was removed in Python 3; it was deemed too obscure, it produces unhelpful error messages and the parameters were un-introspectable. See [PEP 3112 - *Removal of Tuple Parameter Unpacking*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/)