# def function gives invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error

As far as I checked, the indentation is correct, no brackets are missing and I have only imported packages in the previous lines But I still get invalid syntax error.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import bpy
import mathutils
import numpy as np
from math import radians
from mathutils import Vector
from math import radians
from mathutils import Matrix
from bpy import context

def transform_mesh('parent', 'obj_to_be_transformed', (translate_x, translate_y, translate_z), (rot_x,rot_y,rot_z)):

    obj= bpy.data.objects[parent]
    obj1= bpy.data.objects[obj_to_be_transformed]
    initial_mat = obj1.matrix_world

    ...some code

    (x,y,z) = (translate_x, translate_y, translate_z)  
    orig_loc_mat = Matrix.Translation(orig_loc+ mathutils.Vector((x,y,z)))

    ...some more code

    eul = mathutils.Euler((radians(rot_x), radians(rot_y), radians(rot_z)), 'XYZ')
    rot_mat = eul.to_matrix().to_4x4()

    obj.matrix_world = orig_loc_mat * rot_mat * orig_rot_mat * orig_scale_mat 
    bpy.context.scene.update()

    return [initial_loc,initial_rot,initial_scale,loc,rot,scale]


transform_result= transform_mesh('Armature','Coil',(5,0,0),(0,0,1))
print (transform_result)
```

And error is:

```
Error:   File "D:\users\gayathri\Gayathri\Synthetic_data_generation\Final\HMI_Depth_coilA_final_final.blend\Untitled", line 18
def transform_mesh('parent', 'obj_to_be_transformed', (translate_x, translate_y, translate_z), (rot_x,rot_y,rot_z)):
                                                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Comment: Your argument shouldn't be strings: `transform_mesh(parent, obj_to_be_transformed, (translate_x, translate_y, translate_z), (rot_x,rot_y,rot_z)):`

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that nested parameter lists were possible.

Comment: @mkrieger1: Those aren't quite nested parameters, they are tuples as parameters.

Comment: Ok, apparently it's not possible anymore in newer Python versions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28908040

Comment: @Nuageux ok now it points error at `(translate_x, translate_y, translate_z)`

Comment: @mkrieger1 I use python 2.7. :)

Comment: @lost_inthesis Check my answer :)

Comment: It worked when I passed the arguments directly and not as a tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Remove strings from arguments

2- Remove tuples from arguments and attribute them in the function (It might be useful to add some checks)

So, here you are:

```
def transform_mesh(parent, obj_to_be_transformed, translate, rot):
    translate_x, translate_y, translate_z= translate
    rot_x,rot_y,rot_z = rot

    # etc


transform_result= transform_mesh('Armature','Coil',(5,0,0),(0,0,1))
print (transform_result)
```

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer you prefer so your question is marked so solved :)

Answer (score 3):

```
def transform_mesh('parent', 'obj_to_be_transformed',
```

should be

```
def transform_mesh(parent, obj_to_be_transformed,
```

surely?

Answer (score 0):

Tuple parameters are not supported in Python3, but you can pass it as a variable and unpack it after defining the function.

```
def transform_mesh(translate_xyz):
    translate_x, translate_y, translate_z = translate_xyz
```

Comment: I use python 2.7 but will try to pass as just arguments and try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide variables as arguments to the function.

try something like:

```
def transform_mesh(parent, obj_to_be_transformed, t1, t2):
```

Although in the code you have shared, you are always using t1 and t2 as tuples. But in case you want to use x, y and z separately, you can do it by referencing the index:

```
x = t1[0]
y = t1[1]
```

Comment: Or simply `x, y = t1`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Agreed. But only in case when we need all elements individually.

Answer (score 0):

In this line the function parameter are passed in incorrect way,

```
    def transform_mesh('parent', 'obj_to_be_transformed', (translate_x, translate_y, translate_z), (rot_x,rot_y,rot_z)):
```

The Correct syntax would be:

```
    def transform_mesh(parent, obj_to_be_transformed, *translate_xyz, *rot_xyz): #*translate_xyz and *rot-xyz are tuple parameter
```