# Using itertools.product with seed value in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, random-seed

I am in almost the exact same situation as the OP of this question: [Using itertools.product and want to seed a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864809/using-itertools-product-and-want-to-seed-a-value) and I am trying to use the code given in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9865149/15314966) about using seed values with `itertools.product`. This is the original code:

```
from itertools import count, imap

def make_product(*values):
    def fold((n, l), v):
        (n, m) = divmod(n, len(v))
        return (n, l + [v[m]])
    def product(n):
        (n, l) = reduce(fold, values, (n, []))
        if n > 0: raise StopIteration
        return tuple(l)
    return product

def product_from(n, *values):
    return imap(make_product(*values), count(n))

print list(product_from(4, ['a','b','c'], [1,2,3]))
```

I removed `imap` from importing since this is removed in Python 3 and replaced all instances of `imap` with `map`. But I receive a syntax error with the double parenthesis

```
def make_product(*values):
    def fold((n, l), v):
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I make this code work in Python 3 or is there a more efficient method of getting seed values from using `itertools.product`?

Comment: Simply replace `(n, l)` by a single parameter and unpack it into `n, l` inside the function.

Comment: In particular, look at the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28908040/147356).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace it with a single argument and then use tuple unpacking to create `n` and `l`:

```py
def fold(n_l, v):
    (n, l) = n_l
    (n, m) = divmod(n, len(v))
    return (n, l + [v[m]])
```